# Rails not touching "concerns"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my carts controller I have:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart
```

and in controllers/concerns/current_cart.rb I have:

```
module CurrentCart
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  private

def set_cart
  @cart = Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
  @cart = Cart.create
  session[:cart_id] = @cart.id
end
```

But when I click "add to cart" I'm getting the error message

```
"undefined method `set_cart' for #<CartsController"
```

Any insight? Thanks.

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but have you included your module in your controller?

Comment: No such thing as a stupid question when I'm involved.  What does that addition look like in carts controller? @BroiSatse

Comment: You should have line `include CurrentCart`

Comment: @BroiSatse got it. You're a helpful guy.  I'm not sure how to give you "points" or crown you through comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include you module:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  include CurrentCart
  before_action :set_cart, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :invalid_cart
```